# Find a subring $D$ of ring $D'$ such that: $D'$ is a UFD but not a field, and $D$ is an ID but not a UFD.

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a question from a practice exam, not HW, so the most important thing is that I understand the concepts clearly.

I understand the definitions separately, but I'm a little overwhelmed by all of the simultaneous relationships. Can anyone offer me a hint? Or an answer with explanation? I have 7 more questions to tackle, so I am trying to avoid getting hung up for too long on any single question. Thanks in advance...

Comment: ID=Integral Domain?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}]$ is a simple example of a domain that is not a UFD.

Since this ring is a subring of $\mathbb{C}[X]$ (where $X$ is an indeterminate), you're done.

If you want $D$ to be a UFD but not a PID, then consider infinitely many variables.

Comment: Thanks, it suffices that C[x] isn't a field.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: use $2+2+2=3+3$ (within exponents) while looking for a subdomain of $\Bbb C[x]$.

One go-to method for constructing rings with designated algebraic features is to start with a polynomial ring and then build off of it (take subrings/quotients/etc.).